# Mismatching in the received data from USB - Windows Form App (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I am writing a program in C# Visual Studio in Windows Form App (.NET Framework), in that software, I am reading data from a microcontroller via USB.

The data sent is similar to that:

```
$MPU: -1.458, 5.146, 0.977, -0.201, 1.125, 0.261
$GPS: 0.000, 0.000, 0.000
$SPEED: 0.440
```

The data aforementioned was read by the Tera Term VT.

However, the data that I am receiving in the software is similar to that:

```
\r\0\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$GPS: 0??b\u0002?r???b\u0002?r???R\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$SPEED: -0.993
```

The code implemented is:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataIN = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
    }

    private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int idx = 0;

        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' ,'\0','\b'};
        var parts = dataIN.Split(delimiterChars);

        if ((idx = dataIN.IndexOf("$MPU: ")) != -1)
        {
            parts = dataIN.Split(',');
            tBoxAccX.Text = parts[0];
            tBoxAccY.Text = parts[1];
            tBoxAccZ.Text = parts[2];
            tBoxGyrX.Text = parts[3];
            tBoxGyrY.Text = parts[4];
            tBoxGyrZ.Text = parts[5];

        }
        
        if((idx = dataIN.IndexOf("$GPS: ")) != -1)
        {
            parts = dataIN.Split(',');
            tBoxLAT.Text = parts[0];
            tBoxLON.Text = parts[1];
            tBoxSPD.Text = parts[2];
        }

        if ((idx = dataIN.IndexOf("$SPEED: ")) != -1)
        {

            parts = dataIN.Split(',');
            tBoxSPDX.Text = parts[0];
        }
```

}

I had read in some forum that the serialPort1 may have some issue with reading, but I was not able to find this forum again for checking the source.

What could be the reason for that fail in the received message? Is there another method for reading from the serial port?

I am grateful for the helping.

Comment: The problem is that the data first received by TeraTerm VT and the data received by the program do not match. If you do not solve it, you will not be able to proceed. And it is better to pass between serialPort1_DataReceived and ShowData as a parameter instead of interfacing with a variable called dataIN. Also, while splitting using delimiterChars in ShowData, the result is not used for anything, or the presence or absence of each data starting with $ is detected, but the data at the index position is not used. There is no point in splitting the entire dataIN even in processing.